# Memory issues while reading thousands of csv file using pandas "read_csv" with multiprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, amazon-sagemaker, xgboost

I am trying to concatenate thousands of files into one big dataframe which will be further fed to the XGBoost library for training. I am running the training process on the Sagemaker training instance. The training process runs without any error with a small dataset. I have run the training of one day dataset with 4M rows (6GB data) on ml.m5.4xlarge instance (16vCPUs and 64GB memory) which took around 11 hours for training and ran successfully. However, when I am running the training with one week of data which is around 41GB, I am getting memory issues while running the following code:

```
def _read_training_data(training_data_path: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = pd.read_csv(training_data_path)
    return df


def read_training_data(
    paths: List[str]
) -> pd.DataFrame:

    # lazy loading of modules for training
    import multiprocessing as mp
    from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed

    # get directories
    ipaths = train_mdirnames(paths)

    logger.info(f'start parallel data reading with {mp.cpu_count()} core')

    df = None
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=mp.cpu_count()) as executor:
        tasks = [
            executor.submit(_read_training_data, ipath)
            for ipath in ipaths]

        for future in as_completed(tasks):
            try:
                _df = future.result()
                df = _df if df is None else pd.concat([df, _df])
            except Exception as e:
                raise e

    logger.info(f'have read {len(df)} data points')
```

What would be the best way to read huge data in such case?

We are planning to train the data with one month data too which will be even huge. We are planning to read such data using smaller instance or simmilar instance to avoid high cost and then feed the huge concatenated dataframe to the XGBoost library for training.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is given by `XGBoost`. You should use `DMatrix` and use [external memory version](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/external_memory.html):

From documentation:

> When working with large datasets, training XGBoost models can be challenging as the entire dataset needs to be loaded into memory. This can be costly and sometimes infeasible. Staring from 1.5, users can define a custom iterator to load data in chunks for running XGBoost algorithms. External memory can be used for both training and prediction, but training is the primary use case and it will be our focus in this tutorial. For prediction and evaluation, users can iterate through the data themselves while training requires the full dataset to be loaded into the memory.

**Edit**

Maybe you can check your current strategy:

1. Use ThreadPoolExecutor instead of ProcessPoolExecutor. Reading files are IO-bound operations not CPU-bound.
2. Use `pd.concat` each time you get a result is the worst thing you can do with Pandas. Collect your result in a list then when all process are finished (use `wait` instead of `as_completed`) do a single a concatenation operation.

(Note the strategy above doesn't guarantee your code will work)

```
def read_training_data(
    paths: List[str]
) -> pd.DataFrame:

    ...
    from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, wait

    ...
    # workers = mp.cpu_count() * 5 for ThreadPoolExecutor by default
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        tasks = [
            executor.submit(_read_training_data, ipath)
            for ipath in ipaths]

        wait(tasks)

        df = pd.concat([future.result() for future in tasks])

    ...
    return df
```

Comment: Thanks. I have read about "external memory version" but I would like to read the whole data first, and then use that dataframe for training. As per my application design, it will use multi processors to read the whole data and then it will start training. Thus the method defined above should be run correctly first, then only I need to start the training process. Is there a way to read such data first, and then feed it to the xgboost library? I was wondering that the size of the data is 41GB and the memory I am using is 64GB, still I am facing this issue.

Comment: @ethicalguy. I updated my answer with a different strategy. Can you try it please?

Comment: Thank you! I will try it and let you know @Corralien